# Scrapy ImportError: No Module named Tutorial.settings

Tags: python, scrapy, importerror

I seem to have broken the internal code of scrapy too much.

Whenever I try to start a project, I'm getting the import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 109, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 60, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 109, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named Tutorial.settings
```

This seems to have been caused by putting

```
export SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE=Tutorial.settings
```

into terminal.

Comment: Why do you need `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE`?

Comment: If you just entered that in the console, it should be removed once you restart the console. Does it happen in a new console?